# SSIS - Insert all records with matching ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have following staging table and a destination table with the same data:

```
ID | Name | Job    | Hash
1  | A    | IT     | XYZ1
2  | B    | Driver | XYZ2
```

The staging table gets truncated each time and new data gets inserted. Sometimes, a person can get a second job. In that case, we have 2 records with `ID 2` and `Name B, but with a different`job`and`hash` in the staging table.

```
ID | Name | Job    | Hash
1  | A    | IT     | XYZ1
2  | B    | Driver | XYZ2
2  | B    | IT     | XYY4
```

If this happens, I need to insert all records with ID 2 into the destination table. I already have a LKP that checkes for (un-)matching ID's, but how can I "tell" SSIS to take ALL records from the staging table based on the ID's I get from the no match output?

Comment: This is pretty easy if you transfer the data using a SQL task. I don't quite understand you rules though.

Comment: I will try to explain it this way. My problem here is that I have multiple records with the same ID. If one of those records with that ID is different to what we already have in the destination table, I need to insert all the records with that ID. I know how I can insert the ones with changes, but how do I insert all the record with the same ID as the one that had the changes.

Comment: So when there is 2/Driver in the source and target, you insert nothing. When there is 2/Driver and 2/IT in the source and 2/Driver in the target, you insert both records out of the source? Then you'll end up with three records in the target, with two of them being duplicates.

Comment: Yes! Except that we truncate the destination table right before inserting the new data. So we will end up with 2 records being 2/Driver and 2/IT

Comment: hmmm this is really not making much sense. 2/Driver exists so don't load it. Truncate the table and reload.... but you don't load 2/Driver. Next time around does 2/Driver get reloaded? You're going to need to post 3 or 4 cases for how this thing works.

Answer (score 0):

You tell ssis by link the no match output from the lookup to the destination. Assume you have already set 'Redirect rows to no match output' in lookup - general. And in your lookup, you check for **matching** id (not sure how you check unmatching) This way, lookup will output all non-matched rows (by Id) to the destination.

[image]

[image]